# Minecraft server script to start on reboot

Tags: linux, exec, start-stop-daemon

I am using a script I found on a minecraft wiki to automatically start my minecraft server after I reboot.

**console log**

```
 exec start-stop-daemon --stop "stop" --start --chdir /minecraft --chuid minecraft \
 --exec /usr/bin/java -- -Xms1536m -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui 2>&1

 start on runlevel [2345]
 stop on runlevel [^2345]

 respawn
 respawn limit 20 5
```

Every time I try to start the script I get this error.

```
 root@bcserv:/# tail /var/log/upstart/minecraft-server.log
 start-stop-daemon: only one command can be specified
 Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong in my exec syntax? I am running Ubuntu Linux 13.10

Tried removing the --stop "stop" now I am getting this.

root@bcserv:/home/chris# tail /var/log/upstart/minecraft-server.log 
/usr/bin/java already running.

And server does not appear to start.

root@bcserv:/home/chris# ps -aux |grep mine 
root 4564 0.0 0.0 9452 904 pts/2 S+ 17:21 0:00 grep --color=auto mine –

Any other suggestions? It doesn't seem to be picking up my minecraft options.

Comment: Is that Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Yes, 13.10, i corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ' --stop "stop" ' from your exec.

You can only have one Command, --stop or --start, and it looks as if you just need the latter.